# Google Places photos: convert photo_reference to photo url

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to build an app that would display the location name of a nearby place as well as its photo. I'm using Google Places API.

I would like to quickly convert photo_reference to the photo url.

Currently, if you do a nearby search, you would get back this json with 20 nearby locations (I have just pasted 2 locations as the json is too long):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.easyinfo.co.za/\"\u003eEasyinfo.co.za\u003c/a\u003e"
   ],
   "next_page_token" : "CvQB7AAAAEIeM4orJZv2oOV0Lt_mhGBbkvvJIyOwjcHeStpcC5E6fR7pNHw4VsS6cMSKzFRtyjr2LQ67GSvZwFGxw8f72sxwO6NggFNsSyakjO9bKovKpjCn4-uHoQyXESaxMqMci1fet-n9EJEp-VoBVXv-iIb_TvSO26iIXkGUeO-09-19ucYirFahOaNF0pp8ttod59XWgsLPs5r1PnkakrYj5JBgawP83T0ZMwIY52oViQJNGvR6_Bpf73dK68iUnj24w5QNZOql6uAlvFAg-BXs5FKjTWvQO0nR5woo5mJjDzYvbaxQkpMqFQ-BMEnZ3RX10xIQ3twWZWnygJl78DhqZH1DkBoUdcq5qakPBsg1QAn6BdcqdrQFz2g",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -26.2020253,
               "lng" : 28.0500779
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -26.2003339,
                  "lng" : 28.054075
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -26.2041059,
                  "lng" : 28.0470949
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
         "id" : "0765607c0fdb4fae92e59390aff8e9501e98e59c",
         "name" : "Fashion District",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2Vn0h5wOlR4RsOSteUYYM6g",
         "reference" : "CpQBkAAAADboZMmtzHTuxZ85pPFK1fr-V0QslLUKBr8QZssBme4qcqLqs7SvrW-L2lJZg3S0PBYTGzuBU8M1F-Ll72tOdto-hfnxOCBOFfVIQEYe264r-IbWZjiFbuqOHBtU5z99jo3NrTxI29MvE8ogUYccX8FukX8eoAcpKti3Ik2VLvDziRKArf2EDy-6CtSbxeCnthIQyHx09QzBQ-pWEelLd6tCsxoUklzTqP7XbT6WbDCbIa42k1R4Iic",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ],
         "vicinity" : "Johannesburg"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -26.205586,
               "lng" : 28.046573
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "671355d0ee1b5b0bbc1556321cea85ca164601de",
         "name" : "KFC Carlton Centre",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 296,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106295947298714161198\"\u003eKFC Carlton Centre\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAHcsAE2aiv5lIxLEo0c9xMUmH-chXoAeq6yrFPw5uy7LdppAMxBmg8_yvG9y9qaXqsH-IrcPsBD6QQvsfZnpml3U5zgh93nTbm5WONnYmutBSltIr9FwuK-awm8l1vyKeEhD9AqZpJwFLIWms2GeZGPR2GhSPp1JyAU_6_s1Im1_oH5tB4IjyXQ",
               "width" : 607
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJTQABc5kOlR4RAzBKVJ-lZNo",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 3.7,
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAyOipUqSqkrpsKw96nu3YnT72kF2Yj_FWAd3wJkzM6a73ZZu8AJIXGsS-EmvugVGsgcEEcadiPfLJCdX3_molaMarh-sox9sIDp5M9LE6xhE1U-6WMXarQEjNu6_ATfQMdaR0nJPpxCX_AS2vbym1wBIQAA9yUjeeEXHF-HDsjTj9kBoUvRoUMWlNtyY30v0iWqMUzstMHOE",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Commissioner Street, Carlton Centre, Johannesburg"
      }
```

To get the photo url, you will have to call the following for each of the 20 photo_reference in the json - these calls to the google servers take a lot of time to return as you are calling the server 20 individual times:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRdAAAAHcsAE2aiv5lIxLEo0c9xMUmH-chXoAeq6yrFPw5uy7LdppAMxBmg8_yvG9y9qaXqsH-IrcPsBD6QQvsfZnpml3U5zgh93nTbm5WONnYmutBSltIr9FwuK-awm8l1vyKeEhD9AqZpJwFLIWms2GeZGPR2GhSPp1JyAU_6_s1Im1_oH5tB4IjyXQ&key=API-KEY

Each call returns something similar to this which is the actual url for the image - if you click the link below, it goes to the actual picture.

> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-B8FWOhhu2_k/VTdYJeFjRhI/AAAAAAAAAD8/JSJamjx4XyA/s1600-w400/

I think this is a highly inefficient way to obtain the links for the place photos, my rest API calls sometime returns after 10 seconds. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: You need to do your calls to Places API in parallel. Also, the response of the call is supposed to be the actual image, not a url to the image. See https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Do you know how you could the the URL? This works in general in android, but if you had to display this on a website and can't resurface the image yourself, it can be unsafe to send the URL with an API Key